# ¿Como calcular la diferencia de horas entre estas fechas? MySQL

Tags: mysql

La hora y fecha inicial es: 2007-12-31 23:59:59 y la hora de termino es: 2018-03-06 17:44:09, quiero calcular la diferencia de horas entre estas fechas. Pense que con la hora bastaba, pero no, hay que calcular los días también

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, notificacion_update, now()) as horas from notificacion;
```

Esto no funciona, solo calcula minutos entre 2 horas diferentes.

Comment: He contestado la pregunta gracias a invertir 15 segundos en Google con la siguiente búsqueda `difference between dates hours MYSQL`, no digo que la pregunta esté mal, solo que para la próxima te es mas rápido buscar en google que esperar a que alguien conteste en [es.so]

Comment: Gracias, te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Respuesta original de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql/4760637)

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01');
-- result: 22:00:59.


SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00'); 
-- result: 79259  the difference in seconds with the time.
```

Comment: ha funcionado, gracias.

Comment: @RicardoSaucedaRojas Como has comentado que mi respuesta ha ayudado a solucionar tu problema, agradecería que la marcases como "Respuesta Correcta" debajo de "Votar positivo/negativo"

Comment: No me dejaba, después de unos minutos, espere a que pasaran, listo.

Comment: Perfecto! Para la próxima si te va mejor, haz lo que te he comentado, intenta buscar y sino, aquí estaremos. Un saludo

Comment: Si, es que vengo enredado de una pregunta anterior relacionada a todo esto de las fechas y de pronto termine hecho bolas! Una disculpa y gracias!  Se que muchos mas también lo agradecerán.