# Timediff de 2 campos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos como ésta en mysql

```
PLACA    | ENTRADA ----------------- | SALIDA--------------------| TIEMPO 
TY-100   | 14/03/2020 01:30:21 p. m. | 14/03/2020 01:30:28 p. m. |
HD-114   | 16/03/2020 10:54:07 a. m. | 16/03/2020 10:54:09 a. m. |
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme a obtener el tiempo transcurrido desde la hora de entrada hasta la hora de salida en formato 00:00:00. De antemano gracias

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como calcular la diferencia de horas entre estas fechas? MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143915/como-calcular-la-diferencia-de-horas-entre-estas-fechas-mysql)

Comment: Usé el TIMEDIFF, pero tienes que escribir las fechas a comparar, no pasándole los datos almacenados en la tabla

Comment: Simplemente, usa las columnas de fecha como los parámetros de `timediff`

Comment: Usé ésta consulta SELECT TIMEDIFF(`Salida`,`Entrada`) WHERE Placa = "TY-100" pero me tira error

Comment: ¿Cómo guardas tu entrada y salida?

Comment: @misaeloh y cual es el error que obtienes?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(Salida,Entrada) from tabla WHERE Placa = "TY-100"
```

Te falta la sentencia "from" y mencionar la tabla en la consulta